# reactjs - import 3 levels deep react

Tags: reactjs, import, react-context

I am using react and was trying out the new context API for my project which is a "Reddit clone". So my `Context` is created in a file named `provider.js` which is in the `src` folder alongside `App.js`. Now, I have created a `HeaderComponent` in its own folder which imports the `Context` in the following way:

```
import Context from '../provider'
```

I have created another component called `LoginComponent` inside the `HeaderComponent`. And, the `LoginComponent` is in its own folder. Now, I have imported `Context` in the following way:

```
import Context from '.../provider'
```

[image: Tree]

The `../` import worked fine but the `.../` imported throws and error.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/HeaderComponent/LoginComponent/index.js Module not found: Can't
>   resolve '.../provider' in 'C:\Users.......\reddit\reactfe\src\HeaderComponent\LoginComponent'

Comment: It's more efficient you used the <provider> in your App.jsx component instead of add in each component because he shares to everybody component below him and avoids repetition.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Every step up in the folder structure is a `..` followed by a `/`.

```
import Context from '../../provider'
```

Comment: Is this possible `././`?? What would be the difference between `././` and `../../`?

Comment: @SreekarMouli `./` means `the current folder`, so `././` would not take you any further up.

Answer (score 5):

The number of dots don't have the meaning you seem to think they do. Things to remember:

- `../` Up one directory.
- `../../` Up two directories (and so on).
- `./` Same directory as the current one.

With this in mind, since you need to go up one directory (from `LoginComponent` to `HeaderComponent`) and then up one directory again (from `HeaderComponent` to `src`) because that's where `provider.js` resides, you need to do:

```
import Context from '../../provider';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run in your console `ls -la` you see the `.` and `..`. So the `.` it's the current local where are you, and the `..` it's a reference to the parent folder (one level up). So if you need back two folders you need put this two times, this way `../../`.

In your case `import Context from '../../provider'`